# Android: Update Operating System from app

Tags: android, operating-system, updates

Is it possible to update the Android OS/ check for updates for the OS from an Android app? 
To be more precise, the functionality that is provided by the OS to check for updates (Settings->About device->Update(check for updates), Is there a way I could do the same from my app?

Comment: Probably not. Every vendor has it's own custom update mechanism. That's no Android feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but for that you will need to be a system application. A non-system application will not have the permissions required to update the OS.

Comment: SO you mean to say that it is not actually possible for an app developed by any one other than the device manufacturer or android right?

Comment: Yes, basically a non-system app cannot do a system reboot, a must for update and rebooting to bootloader is surely limited to system applications. We cannot do all these actions with our apps.